# How to get firebase storage location from downloadurl?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am use Node.js Firebase Admin SDK. I want get firebase storage location from storage url with token. For example: folder/file.ext

How to do?

This is storage url with token:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-xxxx.appspot.com/o/folder%2F20-5-2016.csv?alt=media&token=b5d45a7f-3ab7-4f9b-b661-3a2187adxxxx

Comment: You could parse it out of the URL path.  What you're showing now suggests a file path of "20-5-2016.csv".

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for reply! How I can do that? There is no API for do this?

Comment: There is no API for nodejs.  There are only APIs for web and mobile clients.  Consider instead also storing the path so you don't have to parse anything.